# clang_complete vim extension not working with STL

Tags: c++, vim, editor, clang, clang-complete

I have installed clang and clang_complete on a Linux system.
I added the following lines to my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
set completeopt-=preview
```

Auto-completion works for my own code. However, it doesn't work with STL container. Even when I just type `std::`, I see a "user defined completion - pattern not found" at the bottom of the screen. What is the problem?

I use Vim 7.3 and clang_complete 1.8

Comment: What happens if you don't add those settings?

Comment: If I don't add the first line, the autocomplete stops working even for my own code. Removing the second line also has no effect on my problem (it only makes the omnicomplete window pop up)

Comment: try deleting the `*.cache` files in `autoload/getopts` where clang_complete is installed

Comment: There seems to be no `getopts' folder in my `~/.vim/autoload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to tell clang_complete to use the clang library (instead of binary) for parsing. This is done by adding the following line to `.vimrc`:

`let g:clang_use_library=1`